# Cloudfront + S3 + HTTPS template also serving unwanted HTTP

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

I have a Cloudformation template for the serving of S3 content over HTTPS, via Cloudfront (see stack at end).

It works fine over HTTPS -

```
(env) justin@justin-XPS-13-9360:~/work/gists/ae46e471eb0e10e877731d787a9fbc2a$ curl -iv https://cloudfront-https-demo.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/index.json
*   Trying 52.218.90.64...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to cloudfront-https-demo.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com (52.218.90.64) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=Washington; L=Seattle; O=Amazon.com, Inc.; CN=*.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
*  start date: Aug  4 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Aug  9 12:00:00 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "cloudfront-https-demo.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com" matched cert's "*.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert Baltimore CA-2 G2
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /index.json HTTP/1.1
> Host: cloudfront-https-demo.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< x-amz-id-2: zVJ4idiIpuyIJIDvXIXbykQe9Po1YebyXEnYMLPkQydhwPLBpkypQfas3vCKuMIfd2cv+yISoqo=
x-amz-id-2: zVJ4idiIpuyIJIDvXIXbykQe9Po1YebyXEnYMLPkQydhwPLBpkypQfas3vCKuMIfd2cv+yISoqo=
< x-amz-request-id: 3E4B1B22DB6EE25D
x-amz-request-id: 3E4B1B22DB6EE25D
< Date: Tue, 25 Aug 2020 19:32:49 GMT
Date: Tue, 25 Aug 2020 19:32:49 GMT
< Last-Modified: Tue, 25 Aug 2020 15:42:18 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 25 Aug 2020 15:42:18 GMT
< ETag: "50521abab7a013be83ee00ded3f9f424"
ETag: "50521abab7a013be83ee00ded3f9f424"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Type: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 19
Content-Length: 19
< Server: AmazonS3
Server: AmazonS3

< 
{"hello": "world"}
* Connection #0 to host cloudfront-https-demo.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com left intact
```

(I pushed an `index.json` file to the bucket)

but a little *too* well, as it also still serves plain HTTP, despite me specifying `https-only` in the template -

```
(env) justin@justin-XPS-13-9360:~/work/gists/ae46e471eb0e10e877731d787a9fbc2a$ curl -iv http://cloudfront-https-demo.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/index.json
*   Trying 52.218.88.232...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to cloudfront-https-demo.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com (52.218.88.232) port 80 (#0)
> GET /index.json HTTP/1.1
> Host: cloudfront-https-demo.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< x-amz-id-2: 9MKgLpvr1BmjF49D98VGThFi0JN4wUzAtIaocNh/8DTss54Zlo+/WFMymbLTdKpUoN0fvvLpMLg=
x-amz-id-2: 9MKgLpvr1BmjF49D98VGThFi0JN4wUzAtIaocNh/8DTss54Zlo+/WFMymbLTdKpUoN0fvvLpMLg=
< x-amz-request-id: 5H1V5SBZAJAY2QAW
x-amz-request-id: 5H1V5SBZAJAY2QAW
< Date: Tue, 25 Aug 2020 19:33:27 GMT
Date: Tue, 25 Aug 2020 19:33:27 GMT
< Last-Modified: Tue, 25 Aug 2020 15:42:18 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 25 Aug 2020 15:42:18 GMT
< ETag: "50521abab7a013be83ee00ded3f9f424"
ETag: "50521abab7a013be83ee00ded3f9f424"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Type: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 19
Content-Length: 19
< Server: AmazonS3
Server: AmazonS3

< 
{"hello": "world"}
* Connection #0 to host cloudfront-https-demo.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com left intact
```

What do I need to do to the template to turn off plain HTTP / leave me with HTTPS only ?

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Parameters:
  AppName:
    Type: String
Resources:
  CloudFrontOAI:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity
    Properties:
      CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig:
        Comment: access-identity-passport-front.s3.amazonaws.com
  SiteCloudFrontDist:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Enabled: true
        DefaultRootObject: index.json
        Origins:
          - DomainName:
              Fn::Sub:
                - ${app_name}.s3.amazonaws.com
                - app_name:
                    Ref: AppName
            Id:
              Fn::Sub:
                - ${app_name}-site-cf-origin
                - app_name:
                    Ref: AppName
            S3OriginConfig:
              OriginAccessIdentity:
                Fn::Sub:
                  - origin-access-identity/cloudfront/${oai}
                  - oai:
                      Ref: CloudFrontOAI
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          AllowedMethods:
            - HEAD
            - GET
            - OPTIONS
          ForwardedValues:
            QueryString: false
          TargetOriginId:
            Fn::Sub:
              - ${app_name}-site-cf-origin
              - app_name:
                  Ref: AppName
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: https-only
        ViewerCertificate:
          CloudFrontDefaultCertificate: true
  SiteBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName:
        Ref: AppName  # NB same as app for URL convenience
  SiteBucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket:
        Ref: SiteBucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action: s3:GetObject
            Effect: Allow
            Principal: '*'
            Resource:
              Fn::Sub:
                - arn:aws:s3:::${bucket_name}/*
                - bucket_name:
                    Ref: SiteBucket
        Version: '2012-10-17'
```

Answer (score 0):

In both cases you are using domain:

```
cloudfront-https-demo.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

This is not a CloudFront domain, which has [format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/LinkFormat.html) of, e.g.:

```
d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net
```

It looks to me that you are using the url of the form:

```
https://<bucket name>.s3-<AWS Region>.amazonaws.com/<object name>
```

However, this is **not CloudFront URL** as indicated in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/GettingStarted.SimpleDistribution.html):

> Use your Amazon S3 URL to verify that your content is publicly accessible, but remember that **this is not the URL** you'll use when you're ready to distribute your content with CloudFront.

Comment: sorry but this point has nothing to do whether HTTPS and/or HTTP endpoints are available under the specified domain name

Comment: @Justin Thanks for letting me know. But your answer is incorrect in the context of the question asks which is about CloudFront's `https-only` option.  At beast your question  is misleading as you ask why `https-only` does not work. The bucket policy you provided is not the answer. The answer is that you are not using CloudFront at all. Thus why even include it in your question?

Comment: CloudFront is absolutely used, it's clearly used and referenced in the template. The correct answer turns out to be that u have to extend the BucketPolicy to include a "secure" condition, in addition to the `https-only` declaration. But I can't answer this question until tomorrow.

Comment: @Justin In your question you are curling `https://cloudfront-https-demo.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/index.json`. This is not cloudfront endpoint. As I explained in my question, cloudfront endpoints are different. But anyway, I'm happy that you found a "solution" anyway.

Comment: But that endpoint is listed as a cloudfront domain, no ? You think I should be curling the cloudfront domain that you suggest ?

Comment: @Justin Yes. If you want to use CloudFront you have to use its endpoint. It will be given in CF console for your distro. Otherwise you are just bypassing CloudFront and accessing bucket directly. CloudFront endpoints are only https anyway. With the way you set it up, your bucket will be accessible without CloudFront. But how to make it private is a different question in my view. Thus my answer was about the endpoints only.

Comment: OK I didn't realise that. I thought Cloudfront required you to specify a domain that looked like the S3 domain. I will try your suggestion later this evening. Could we move this discussion to chat ? I will un- downvote your answer when then system lets me as a gesture of good will :) Thank you.

Comment: PS Cloudfront very confusing. Even worse than API Gateway.

Comment: @Justin No problem. Please check. Sadly I can't chat now. CloudFront is quite complex. But please let me know how it will go, once you check. Thanks.

Comment: What I don't understand is this. In the template in the original post, how does the Cloudfront distribution know which bucket to access when looking for data ? It would seem to be in the Origins property, where I assumed you had to put a DomainName which somehow referenced the S3 bucket. DomainName is a required property of Origins; Origins is not required, but if I delete it, then the CloudFront distribution and the Bucket seem disconnected, no ?

Comment: Confirmed; if I add a randomised domain name I get `The parameter Origin DomainName does not refer to a valid S3 bucket`

Comment: If I try the earlier outputted CloudFront domain, I get *redirected* to the specified DomainName -

Comment: ```$ curl https://d2gyp3fg1im05u.cloudfront.net/index.json
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>TemporaryRedirect</Code><Message>Please re-send this request to the specified temporary endpoint. Continue to use the original request endpoint for future requests.</Message><Endpoint>cloudfront-https-demo.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com</Endpoint><Bucket>cloudfront-https-demo</Bucket><RequestId>9D8B04753D397F50</RequestId><HostId>Fedfedgx98oqdVzHmuA8+i5HJWeK3FJ0+Gl/wbe/AE7drsn645kboceiJrK1RhmAbW4kTSfje4U=</HostId></Error>```

Comment: (last one, promise) and I think also that the `cloudfront-https-demo.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` endpoint is not in fact an S3 endpoint, but rather a CloudFront endpoint - firstly because it's specified within the CloudFront config (and just happens to pattern match an S3 bucket), but also because (non- CloudFront) S3 website URLs always contain `s3-website`, which this does not.

Comment: @Justin Its fine. I think we are talking about different things. But anyway, most important is that it works. And since question started to be intriguing I also upvoted it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Need to modify the bucket policy to disable non- secure connections -

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "ExamplePolicy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowSSLRequestsOnly",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/*",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "true"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```